# Async CTP for WP7 trigger ID_CAP_LOCATION

Tags: windows-phone-7, location, async-ctp

I'm trying to use Async CTP for WP7 , but when I'm including AsyncCtpLibrary_Phone.dll, ID_CAP_LOCATION capability it's detected by CapabilityDetection.
Obvious, I don't use and Location service in my project.
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I can't understand your question - please could you edit it?

Comment: It might be internal to the library as it has been mentioned here: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/82412/510713.aspx Are you sure there are no other libraries or controls in your project that could require the `Location` capability (e.g. Analytics or Map control)

Comment: I'm sure I don't have any other library that could require Location capability. If I remove AsyncCtpLibrary from project, ID_CAP_LOCATION is not detected anymore. Maybe someone else can confirm this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AsyncCtpLibrary_Phone.dll includes the method `ResolveAddressTaskAsync` which takes parameters from the `System.Device.Location` namespace.

The capability detection process determines the need for the "ID_CAP_LOCATION" by analysing all DLLs in the XAP and looking for use of this namespace. This is the case whether you use that code in your app or not.

There is no way round this in 7.0. However, tThe detection rules in 7.1 are more specific with regards "ID_CAP_LOCATION" so this shouldn't be the case.